# What is the best way to submitting article with image without refreshing page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a remote form which users use to share articles, when i click submit button an ajax request will be sent then append result to articles list.

What i want to do is add possibility to add image to articles, firstly i added `multipart: true` to my form and i installed a gem called `remotipart` which help me to upload image via ajax, i don't know if is secure to upload image via ajax but it works (even don't know if remotipart work in all navigators) , the only problem is that there is issue with firefox : after submitting the form in the bottom of navigator there is a flash message "Transferring data from [localhost]" never stops showing.

after some reflection i decide to use another method, which is use separate form : one for article content working via ajax, and another for image working with normal request using iframe, so when i click submit button, image is submitted first via iframe, then after an ajax request is submitted to update the article content

this means in total i will have 2 successive requests. is this a good way to do this think ? i will also be thankful for any other suggestion

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart gem to do "ajax" uploads to the server.